# How to safely edit files in mounted BTRFS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, btrfs, manjaro

I broke my Manjaro Linux by putting wrong value into /etc/environment.
I've booted from Manjaro live usb and mounted my partition using "Disks" utility (also tried `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 ./mount` with the same result).
Now I want to fix /etc/environment by editing it but the mounted filestructure looks different, I've found my file in `/run/media/manjaro/567.../@/etc/environment`.

- The filesystem seems to be mounted in readonly mode, how do I make it editable?
- Is it safe to edit the file directly if I will be able to make it editable?
- If it is not safe to edit files directly I have timeshift backups in `/run/media/manjaro/567.../timeshift-btrfs`. How do I use them?